# jQuery issue with chaining isNumeric

Tags: jquery

I've got a simple conditional that checks if an id is equal to something
and also checks if it is a number. I'm also using isNumeric with a combination
of .length. But for some reason the isNumeric part is not working as I can enter 
a string of letters and it doesn't validate.  Any ideas?

```
var $this = $(this);
if(this.id == "userName" && $.isNumeric($this.val()).length < 10 ){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're having problems is that this:

```
$.isNumeric( $this.val() )
```

returns `true` or `false`, and checking the length of a boolean makes no sense, as `true` or `false` will never have a length over 10, as booleans does'nt have a length, and returns "undefined" ?

Maybe you meant this :

```
if (
    this.id == "userName" 
    && 
    $.isNumeric( $this.val() ) 
    && 
    $this.val().length < 10 
   ){
      // do something if the value is numeric, and the string length is under 10
   }
```

Comment: thanks @adeneo it's odd but I'm still getting the same results. If I input: **$.isNumeric( $this.val() ) ** as a letter it's not validating.

Comment: Not sure I get it, as a "letter" how exactly. You're only allowing numbers, like 434243 ?

Comment: Try replacing the isNumeric line with `/\D/g.test(this.value)`

Comment: It's a regex to check that the string contains only numbers, the same thing isNumeric is supposed to do internally ?